# MAX5725 SPI mode

Tags: spi, dac

I'm reading the datasheet of [MAX5725](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5723-MAX5725.pdf) but I cannot understand which SPI mode it uses.
At page 18 I read:

> [...] the  data  is  shifted  in  synchronously  and  latched  into  the  input  register  on  each  falling  edge  of  the  serial  clock  input  (SCLK).

This limits the SPI mode to 1 (clock idle low, sampling on second edge) or 2 (clock idle high, sampling on first edge).

I also looked at Figure 1 where there are the SPI signals, but unfortunately it's not so clear the idle state of the clock signal. Following this figure both modes would fit.

From which other parameter should I understand the actual SPI mode it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can use either mode. When writing to the chip, it does not matter if clock idles low or high, the falling edges still load data in. For reading, the chip allows you to specify which clock edge you want to use for reading.